# Prove the difference between two second order non homogeneous EDO solutions goes to zero when the independent variable goes to infinity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the ODE $ay''+by'+cy=g(t)$ where  $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b,c>0$. Given that $Y_1(t),Y_2(t)$ are solutions to the ODE, prove $Y_1(t)-Y_2(t) \rightarrow 0$ when $t \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I know the homogeneous solution goes to zero when a,b,c are positive constants. I'm having trouble discussing about the non homogenous part.

Comment: What do you mean by EDO? Do you mean ODE?

Comment: @Amzoti You're probably right. The OP is brazilian and in portuguese ODE translates to 'equações diferenciais ordinárias'.

Comment: @GitGud: Thank you, perfect clarification! Regards

Comment: Sorry @Amzoti, I corrected the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the characteristic polynomial of $ay''+by'+cy=\bf 0$ is $ax^2+bx+c$ whose roots are $\color{grey}{x_1=}\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $\color{grey}{x_2=}\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

Clearly $x_2$ has negative real part.

The same happens for $x_1$ because, if $b^2-4ac\leq 0$, the real part of $x_1$ is just $\dfrac{-b}{2a}\color{grey}{<0 }$. And if $b^2-4ac>0$, consider this: clearly $-4ac<0$ and
$$\begin{align} -4ac< 0 &\implies b^2-4ac\leq b^2\\
&\implies\sqrt{b^2-4ac}< \sqrt{b^2}\\
&\implies \sqrt{b^2-4ac}< b\\
&\implies -b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}< 0,\end{align}$$
so $-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}< 0$.

Since $x_1, x_2$ have negative real parts, the solutions of $ay''+by'+cy=\bf 0$ are such that they approach $0$ as $t$ goes to infinity.

Finally prove that $Y_1-Y_2$ is a solution of $ay''+by'+cy=\bf 0$.

Comment: @BabakS. Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's not safe to suppose the characteristic polynomial has no real roots for all $a,b,c>0$. Please note [this example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B3y%27%2By%3D3): $y''+3y'+y=3$.

Comment: @srodriguex I apologize for giving you a wrong hint. I did think about what I said, but made a wrong computation in my head that led to a wrong hint. I fixed the answer with all the details. Desculpa ae, mermão.

Comment: Thanks @GitGud. I belive a easier way to see why the real part are negatives is $|b^2| <| b^2-4ac| \implies |b| < |\sqrt{b^2-4ac}|$. And $Y_1-Y_2$ goes to $0$ as the homogeneous solution goes to $0$ and the particular solution is cancelled in the subtraction.