# DE's: Behaviour at $t$ at infinity: $a(Y_1 - Y_2)'' + b(Y_1 - Y_2)' + c(Y_1 - Y_2) = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the DE:

$ay'' + by' + cy = g(t)$ (*)

where $a, b, c,$ are positive.

**If $Y_1(t)$ and $Y_2(t)$ are solutions to (*), show that $Y_1(t) - Y_2(t)$ goes to $0$ as $t$ goes to infinity. Is this true if $b = 0$?**

So far I've got:

Using the fact that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are solutions, we can subtract equations getting the new equation:

$a(Y_1 - Y_2)'' + b(Y_1 - Y_2)' + c(Y_1 - Y_2) = 0$.

But I'm not sure what next step I need to make to prove the claim. If $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are polynomials I think it follows easily that we must have $Y_1 - Y_2 = 0$ I also see why this must be the case for trig functions and exponentials (for trig it follows from the fact that $sin$ and $cosine$ are linearly independent, and for the exponentials from the fact that they are all positive, but $a, b, c$ must be positive too.) But I'm sure how to prove this rigorously. Also I don't understand why we are looking at $t$ going to infinity.

I've actually found a counterexample for it not holding if $b$ = 0:

Take $Y_1 - Y_2 = sint$, $a = c$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561176/prove-the-difference-between-two-second-order-non-homogeneous-edo-solutions-goes?rq=1).

Comment: Your example shows it is not true if b = 0. The question says b must be positive though.